# Creating another map function in Hazelcast?

Tags: dictionary, cluster-computing, in-memory-database, hazelcast

When i run hazelcast on my terminal I use m.put to create a new map function.
I want to create another map function with a different name. Is it possible to do so?
Is there a seperate command to create a new map function?
Please help..!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer myself from Stackoverflow.!
You can use the command ns [the_map_name] //switch the namespace for using the distributed queue/map/set/list (defaults to "default")

m is not the name of map, it is part of the command.

For example you have a map named "students" and want to put a new record to this map. You should:

> ns students
>   m.put(key, value)